# Aprendi a passar um vetor como parâmetro, gostaria de alterar e retornar o vetor (vetor_y1) pra main, tem como fazer sem alocar? Por favor

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
int vetor_y1();
int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    int i,j;
    printf("Inf. o tamanho do vetor: ");
    scanf("%d",&i);


    int vetor[i];
    for(j=0;j<i;j++){
        printf("Inf. o %dº valor: ",j+1);
        scanf("%d",&vetor[j]);
    }

    vetor_y1(vetor, j);


    printf("\n");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
int vetor_y1(int vetor[], int j){
    int i=j;
    int vetor_y1[j];
    for(j=0;j<i;j++){
        vetor_y1[j]=vetor[j];
    }
    printf("Vetor Y\n");
    for(j=0;j<i;j++){
        if(vetor_y1[j]>=10 && vetor_y1[j]<=40){
            printf("%d ",vetor_y1[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sem alocar o que? Tem algum requisito para o código ser assim? Ele pode ser bem mais simples que isto.

Comment: O vetor recebido na função é um ponteiro, logo quando altera na função já altera os valores, e por isso não faz sentido retornar

Comment: Eu estou aprendendo, então gostaria de fazer com que o vetor_y1 retornasse para a main, e printar na main, porém não é necessário já que fiz o exercício, apenas tenho essa dúvida e gostaria de aprender porém não consegui

Comment: Não há nenhum requisito, apenas quero aprender a retorna-lo e printar na main

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> gostaria de alterar e retornar o vetor pra main

Quando passa um vetor para uma função está na verdade a passar o ponteiro para o primeiro elemento.

Considere o seguinte exemplo:

```
void muda(int arr[]){
    arr[0] = 9;
}

int main(){
    int array[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    muda(array);

    printf("%d", array[0]); //9
}
```

[Veja o exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/2I4DjZ)

Aqui vê que de fato alterando os valores do vetor dentro da função `muda` altera o vetor original que está no `main`. Isto acontece porque a função recebeu o endereço de memoria onde está o vetor, logo consegue ir á memoria e alterar no local onde ele está.

**Isto torna o retorno inútil** uma vez que já tem o array alterado no `main`.

Mas se quisesse podia faze-lo (**embora não seja aconselhado**):

```
int* muda(int arr[]){ //aqui o tipo tem de ser definido como ponteiro para int
    arr[0] = 9;
    return arr;
}
```

E chamar assim:

```
array = muda(array);
```

> gostaria de fazer com que o `vetor_y1` retornasse para a `main`, e printar na main

Assim como viu em cima a função `vetor_y1` que tem já altera o `vetor` na `main`, logo basta na `main` imprimir diretamente os valores que precisa.

O retorno de um vetor apenas faria sentido caso tivesse gerado um novo vetor dentro da função. Aconselho também a aprofundar os seus estudos em ponteiros que lhe vão dar uma ideia bem mais clara de como tudo isto funciona.